# Can the Early 2016 MacBook (not Pro) Drive Two Thunderbolt Displays?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

This question is NOT about how to connect two Thunderbolt displays — there are plenty of questions asked here about that, but whether or not the graphics chip in the Early 2016 MacBook 1.3 GHz Core m7 (M7-6Y75) has the power to drive two external displays (Apple Thunderbolt Display) at 2560 x 1440 resolution?

Here's the backstory. I have a MacBook Pro connected to two Thunderbolt displays. I am considering replacing it, but I love my dual Thunderbolt displays. I would like to replace it with the newest 2016 MacBook, but concerned it won't have enough power to drive the two displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What those specs are saying is that this model can simultaneously support the **internal display as well as up to 3840x2160 at 30 Hz on an external display**, both at "millions of colours."

In other words, connecting two external Thunderbolt Displays is **not officially supported by Apple**. The two displays are the internal display and an external display.

Answer (score 1):

I should have looked closer to the tech specs on the Apple website:

> Dual display and video mirroring: simultaneously supports full native
>   resolution on the built-in display and up to 3840 by 2160 pixels at
>   30Hz on an external display, both at millions of colors.

Based on this I can only run my built-in display and one external display, and only at 30Hz.

Comment: There is a hack to run it at 60Hz. Check out 9to5Mac - How-To: Drive a 4K display at 60 Hz with the 2016 MacBook: https://9to5mac.com/2016/06/04/how-to-enable-4k-60hz-resolution-2016-macbook/